# Update css, avoid rendering failure cause of cache

Tags: css

I'm about to make a major update to my web app. I'm afraid the users previously cache stored css file will cause rendering failure and they will close the app. Whats the best practice to avoid this? Will it help if i rename my css-files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the URLs to the CSS files.

You can limit the change to the query string portion of the URL.

Comment: Ok. So from assets/css/main.css to assets/css/v2/main.css?

Comment: I'd go with `assets/css/main.css?2` myself (and probably make `2` be my VCS version number or build timestamp).